# Can't clone bitbucket repository with sourcetree and without

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

MacOs Yosemite

I try clone repository with sourcetree. It began cloning but through some minutes it show me alert "Confirm Delete Repository" with text "You opted to delete repositories on disk but the repository "(null)" contains uncommitted files which will be lost forever if you delete this repository. Are you sure you want to delete the repository on disk?" So i can't clone

I try clone with terminal. After cloning terminal write message: "remote: Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host." But it's not clong all my repository and subrepository.

How I can get repository from bitbucket? I have 2 repositories, that I cloning 2-3 monthes ago on my macbook, and it was all good. Repository is cloned on my work under my account too without problems. But now I try get 2 new repositories on my mac, and I have same issues, that I described

In sourcetree I got such error:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/{my_repository}
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 19 changesets with 115 changes to 58 files
updating to branch default
cloning subrepo framework from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/{my_repository}
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1004 changesets with 4877 changes to 2384 files (+3 heads)
remote: Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: Have you tried using `hg clone -U ssh://.....` to clone the repo without updating the working directly? That won't necessarily get you over the subrepo problem but it's a place to start so you're at least not cloning everything from BitBucket every time.

Comment: Additionally, could you try cloning with '--verbose --debug --traceback'?